# Getting gradle error when building expo development project for android Execution failed for task ':expo-splash-screen:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas

I'm running into an issue when I try to build the android version of my app for development.

I initially uploaded this to the cloud to build and got this error. The command I ran was

`eas build --profile development --platform android`

Then I tried running it locally but tagging on the `--local` flag at the end and I still keep running into this error.

I've run `npx expo-doctor` and all of my dependencies, including the splash screen are correct. How can I dig deeper into what's causing this error?

Do you need my settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'Maleosii'
    
    apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../scripts/autolinking.gradle");
    useExpoModules()
    
    apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../native_modules.gradle");
    applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
    
    include ':app'
    includeBuild(new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native/gradle-plugin/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile())
```

or my build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '33.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '21')
        compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '33')
        targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '33')
        kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion') ?: '1.8.10'
        frescoVersion = findProperty('expo.frescoVersion') ?: '2.5.0'

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2')
        classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../android'))
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('jsc-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../dist'))
        }

        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

[image]